# Force restart iPhone using a software (without iPhone's permission)

Tags: iphone, ios, restart

My iPhone's power button is not working. I've been using assistive touch option for a long time.

However yesterday my iPhone was acting up and couldn't turn it off by long pressing assistive touch's "power button" option. So I decided to restart it by resetting network settings. But it didn't restart it so I repeatedly pressed "reset network settings" option for like 3-4 times. After that iPhone entered to lock screen and now there's an overlay text with the message "Resetting iPhone". It's been that way for like 12 hours already. But apparently nothing happens. I can use assistive touch, above this overlay but it doesn't do anything. Behind this transparent overlay, iPhone's clock works fine. I receive calls but can't answer them, even using headset.  It's very strange I've never seen anything like this before.

I want to restart the phone but I'm out of options. Data and Wifi was turned off so can't use even iCloud to reset. iTunes picks up phone but asks for iPhone permission to access it. By pressing "trust this computer" option. 
Last resort is waiting for battery is fully drained. But If I can use some kind of a tool to force restart I think this issue will be resolved.

I used a iPhone rebooting tool, but it still requires iPhone's permission ("trust this computer" option) which I can not access.

Anything else I can do here?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way that I can think of to do it via software, but I do have a crude workaround idea.

You can let the battery die (you can accelerate this process by turning up the screen brightness), then plug in the phone. Crude, but the phone will turn itself off when the battery dies and turn itself on when you plug it in. It's effectively a restart.

Comment: I can not turn up the screen brightness because screen is locked. Looks like I have to wait till the battery dies itself..  I remember there was some jailbreaking tools that lets you do things like force restarting. But I couldn't find any yet.